# ORACLE APEX : Authentication against LDAP Distribution List

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5

I want to authenticate Oracle APEX user against LDAP, but only if he/she belongs to a particular distribution list.

Example : assume I have distribution list 'ADMIN_GRP', the APEX application should allow access to user only if he/she is member of 'ADMIN_GRP'.

Any clues ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For admin ones, please ask at http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TheImpaler - this is indeed a programming question. Oracle has DBMS_LDAP package. Just want to know how it can be used.

Comment: The actual logic is going to depend heavily on how your particular organization has chosen to organize information within LDAP (it's a bit like asking how you'd get an employee's address from a relational database without telling us anything about the schema and where this information is stored).  The `dbms_ldap` documentation has sample code https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/network.920/a96577/smplcode.htm#636613 that you can go through.  You'd need to know what DNs and attributes to use in your particular LDAP impleentation